# Various tricks to elevate process inside process

Tags: security, winapi

So I'm trying to see if I can gain elevated privileges for the current process by duplicating a token from an elevated process.

1.In process 1 I'm calling process 2 with admin, passing process 1's PID:

```
RunAsAdmin(L"test.exe /admin pid"); // Calls ShellExecute with runas and waits to finish
```

2.In elevated process I'm duplicating an elevated token (error checking removed):

```
HANDLE h3 = 0;
OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, &h3);

// Verification if token is elevated, yes it is
TOKEN_ELEVATION te;
TOKEN_ELEVATION_TYPE tet;
DWORD l;
GetTokenInformation(h3, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS::TokenElevation, &te, sizeof(te), &l);
GetTokenInformation(h3, TOKEN_INFORMATION_CLASS::TokenElevationType, &tet, sizeof(tet), &l);

// Duplicate the token to the process which we have the PID from cmdline:

auto hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, false, pid);
HANDLE nh = 0;
DuplicateHandle(GetCurrentProcess(), h3, hProcess, &nh, 0, 0,DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

// Verification if new handle is elevated, yes it is

// Pass token to process
PassNewTokenToProcess(nh); // Currently I'm using clipboard, later I will use file mapping.
```

3.In process 1 I'm getting the token:

```
HANDLE hTok = GetTokenFromClipboard();

// Verify it's elevated, yes it is.

// Duplicate it to myself
HANDLE hTok2;
DuplicateTokenEx(hTok, TOKEN_ALL_ACCESS, 0, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &hTok2);

// Verify it's elevated, yes it is.

// Impersonate
ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hTok2); // Returns true

RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, L"SOFTWARE\\TestXXX", 0, 0, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, ...); 
// Fails error 5 access denied
```

The last call fails. I know I'm doing something wrong, but the tokens are elevated as `GetTokenInformation` returns.

Is there somewhere I could verify that the new token indeed would not be able to actually elevate the current process?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Isn't it known that you can't do this?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I'm looking for a way to know I can't do this, i.e. some error returned by the functions I'm calling.

Comment: You are expected to create a new elevated process. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: You are already launching an elevated process, so just make that process do the work you need elevated rights for. There is no point in trying to pass the elevated token back to an unelevated process so it can impersonate.

Comment: @David: While recommended, creating a new process lacks an important feature: The ability to restore the process' security token. That's a common scenario, where elevation is only required for a short sequence of operations. Elevating a single thread would be a nice solution, allowing you to either restore its token, or let it run to completion. I have always wondered, why there is nothing in the API to account for this common scenario.

Comment: you have no *SeImpersonatePrivilege*, as result `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` set token for your thread with .. `SecurityIdentification` impersonation level. as result now all security checks will fail with access denied or `STATUS_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL` (`ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL`)

Comment: call `OpenThreadToken` (*OpenAsSelf  = true*) after `ImpersonateLoggedOnUser` and then `GetTokenInformation` with `TokenImpersonationLevel` and you understand your problem

Comment: so unfortunatelly if you have not `SeImpersonatePrivilege` you can not impersonate another token. not elevated process by default have no it

Comment: @IInspectable there is something in the API to handle that scenario, actually. Move your admin work into a COM object and then use the COM Elevation Moniker to instantiate that object when needed. The COM object will run in an elevated state, without having to elevate the whole process.

Comment: @RemyLebeau - but in current thread (process) context will be run only proxy of object, real com object will be run in separate elevated process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem here in call

```
// Impersonate
ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(hTok2); // Returns true
```

despite [`ImpersonateLoggedOnUser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/securitybaseapi/nf-securitybaseapi-impersonateloggedonuser) return true, really function can do not what you wait.

> All impersonate functions, including **ImpersonateLoggedOnUser** allow the
>   requested impersonation if one of the following is true:
>
> - The requested impersonation level of the token is less than    **SecurityImpersonation**, such as **SecurityIdentification** or **SecurityAnonymous**.
> - The caller has the **SeImpersonatePrivilege** privilege.
>
> ...

so even for valid *hToken* api can fail, but in not usual way - instead of return false and set error code - api anyway return true, but silently reset impersonation level of thread token to `SecurityIdentification`. after this all calls, which do security checks fail with `ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL` or `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

in general not elevated process have not `SeImpersonatePrivilege` privilege, as result when we try impersonate with elevated token, call **formally** not fail but, we got `SecurityIdentification` impersonation level instead `SecurityImpersonation`. even if elevated (or *LocalSystem*, or even kernel mode) try set elevated token to thread in process which have not `SeImpersonatePrivilege` privilege - this try set only `SecurityIdentification` level.

we can easy check this by `OpenThreadToken` call and query it `TokenImpersonationLevel`.

full test code:

```
inline ULONG BOOL_TO_ERROR(BOOL f)
{
    return f ? NOERROR : GetLastError();
}

void WINAPI entry(void*)
{
    HANDLE hToken, hThread, hDupToken;
    ULONG dwError;

    // for attach debugger
    MessageBoxW(0, 0, GetCommandLineW(), 0);

    if (PWSTR c = wcschr(GetCommandLineW(), '*'))
    {
        ULONG dwThreadId = wcstoul(c + 1, &c, 16);

        dwError = ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;

        if (!*c && dwThreadId)
        {
            dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(OpenProcessToken(GetCurrentProcess(), TOKEN_DUPLICATE|TOKEN_IMPERSONATE, &hToken));

            if (dwError == NOERROR)
            {
                dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(DuplicateToken(hToken, ::SecurityImpersonation, &hDupToken));

                CloseHandle(hToken);

                if (dwError == NOERROR)
                {
                    if (hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_SET_THREAD_TOKEN, FALSE, dwThreadId))
                    {
                        dwError = RtlNtStatusToDosError(
                            ZwSetInformationThread(hThread, ThreadImpersonationToken, &hDupToken, sizeof(hDupToken))
                            );

                        CloseHandle(hThread);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dwError = GetLastError();
                    }

                    CloseHandle(hDupToken);
                }
            }
        }
        ExitProcess(dwError);
    }

    WCHAR file[MAX_PATH], params[32];

    if (GetModuleFileNameW(0, file, RTL_NUMBER_OF(file)))
    {
        SHELLEXECUTEINFOW sei = { 
            sizeof(sei), SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS, 0, L"runas", file, params 
        };

        swprintf(params, L"*%x", GetCurrentThreadId());

        dwError = BOOL_TO_ERROR(ShellExecuteExW(&sei));

        if (dwError == NOERROR)
        {
            switch (WaitForSingleObject(sei.hProcess, INFINITE))
            {
            case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
                if (GetExitCodeProcess(sei.hProcess, &dwError))
                {
                    break;
                }
            case WAIT_FAILED:
                dwError = GetLastError();
                break;
            default:
                __debugbreak();
                dwError = ERROR_GEN_FAILURE;
            }

            CloseHandle(sei.hProcess);

            if (dwError == NOERROR)
            {
                if (OpenThreadToken(GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_QUERY, TRUE, &hToken))
                {
                    ULONG cb;
                    SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL sil;
                    if (GetTokenInformation(hToken, ::TokenImpersonationLevel, &sil, sizeof(sil), &cb))
                    {
                        DbgPrint("ImpersonationLevel = %x\n", sil);
                    }
                    CloseHandle(hThread);
                }

                union {
                    HANDLE hFile;
                    HKEY hKey;
                };

                hFile = CreateFileW(file, 0, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

                if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
                {
                    DbgPrint("CreateFile=%u\n", GetLastError());
                }
                else
                {
                    CloseHandle(hFile);
                }

                dwError = RegOpenKeyExW(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, 0, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);

                if (dwError)
                {
                    DbgPrint("OpenKey=%u\n", dwError);
                }
                else
                {
                    RegCloseKey(hKey);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    ExitProcess(dwError);
}
```

so this is by design - disable not elevated (less then *High Integrity Level*) processes impersonate elevated tokens, by remove `SeImpersonatePrivilege` from process token. this is effective dissable all impersonating attemps for set high or more Integrity Level